# Flip images on finger movements

Tags: android

I have to flip the images depends on the movement of finger.The movement of finger is either in clock wise direction or in anti clockwise direction.If the finger moves in clockwise direction I have to show the next image using shownext() of flipper otherwise I have to use the showprevious() of flipper to show the previous one.Sorry for the bad english.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So, what kind of help do you expect? Can you show what you've done so far to resolve your problem? Any tutorials found? Any unsuccessful tries?

Comment: My requirement is how it is possible to track the circular motion of the finger using ontouchlistner

Answer (score 0):

Each movement of the finger will give you an x- and y-coordinate. Then you have to compare these coordinates to the previous and this will tell you wether the finger is moving clockwise or counter clockwise:

```
x-- && y-- = counter clockwise
x-- && y++ = clockwise
x++ && y-- = clockwise
x++ && y++ = counter clockwise
```

The only problem is that the finger might not go in the same direction the whole time, so you might check only every 10th oder 20th coordinate pair.

Comment: 10th oder 20th coordinate means

Comment: That you don't check each new pair of coordinates. Use an iterator to check only every 10th or 20th pair of coordinates in order to filter false information (i.e. if the finger moves "back" a little bit)